# Windows Server 2016 - Is it possible to install different web browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, safari, microsoft-edge, windows-server-2016

I'm using [Windows Server 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2016) and there I'm using [Telerik test studio](https://www.telerik.com/teststudio) for running automated tests. The problem is that I would like to test my software in **Microsoft Edge, Safari, & Chrome.** Unfortunately I haven't been able to install these browsers so far.

I could of course use something like [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) or a VM on WS 2016 but the problem with this approach is, that the machine where WS 2016 runs is quite "underpowered" and thus would make the whole thing really slow.

Can I install Safari & Chrome on Windows Server 2016?

Comment: "_Unfortunately I haven't been able to install these browsers so far._" - what have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: Windows Server 2016 is WIndows 10 in disguise. This means, that you have no say in what software runs on it - this is solely Microsoft's choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer:

In Windows server you are able to install whatever you want (the difference between Server edition and desktop edition are the features you can enable on it, but basically it works like other OS of MS family) but you have to have the rights to perform installations!

If you have not the installation rights, request to the server administrators to install the required applications for you.

Other else you could use the portable version of the browser, chrome and firefox have for sure a portable version for safari I'm not sure.

- [Chrome Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable)
- [FirefoxPortable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)

Comment: You can install Chrome without admin rights, can't you?

Comment: You can try to install it in a location the user can write in, it should work fine. I mean, instead "c:\Program Files" choose a path in the user folder I.E. "c:\Users\%USERNAME%\Programs". Maybe chrome do it automatically, but not sure on this.